# Find unmerged Git branches?

Tags: git, git-merge, branching-and-merging

I have a Git repository with many branches, some of them already merged and some not. Since the number of branches is quite large, how can I determine which branches have not yet been merged? I would like to avoid having to do an "octopus" merge and re-merging branches that have already been merged.

Comment: First I was laughing about the term of the "octopus merge". But in case you didn't know, like me: That's the official name of a merge strategy :-) See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge or https://www.atlassian.com/de/git/tutorials/using-branches/merge-strategy

Answer (score 567, accepted):

Try this:

```
git branch --merged master
```

It does what it says on the tin (lists branches which have been merged into `master`). You can also pull up the inverse with:

```
git branch --no-merged master
```

If you don't specify `master`, e.g...

```
git branch --merged
```

then it will show you branches which have been merged into the current `HEAD` (so if you're on `master`, it's equivalent to the first command; if you're on `foo`, it's equivalent to `git branch --merged foo`).

You can also compare upstream branches by specifying the `-r` flag and a ref to check against, which can be local or remote:

```
git branch -r --no-merged origin/master
```

Comment: If you merge `foo` into `master`, it will appear in the `git branch --merged master` list. But what happens if you commit once more to `foo`? Does it no longer appear in that list, or does it, as even though it has new commits, it was *at one point* merged into `master`?

Comment: @CraigOtis It will no longer appear in the list. `--merged` only lists branches that are *completely* merged into the given branch.

Comment: and `gitk --remotes --not origin/master` will show you the commits on each branch that have not been merged to master.

Comment: Imagine this... a git answer that's easy to understand and use!

Comment: Is there a way to get the list without checking out the branch? Like pointing to the server and then get the list?

Comment: As I found, the `git branch --no-merged master` shows only my local branches. It doesn't show any branch that was not checked out on my computer and created by someone else.

Comment: @AntonDanilchenko which is exactly as you'd expect.  If you wanted to see remote branches as well use the `--all` flag.

Comment: Does this correctly find branches that have been **squash merged** into the target branch? Frequently squashes throw off tools that need direct paths between branches to work correctly, `gitversion` for example.

Answer (score 83):

You can also use the `-r` parameter to show remote branches that were not merged into master:

```
git branch -r --merged master

git branch -r --no-merged
```

Comment: or `-a` to see both remote and local at the same time

Comment: Should that last one be    git branch -r --no-merged master   ?

Answer (score 31):

**If a branch is merged already, merging it again won't do anything.** So you don't have to be worried about "re-merging" branches that are already merged.

To answer your question, you can simply issue

```
 git branch --merged
```

to see the merged branches or

```
 git branch --no-merged
```

to see the unmerged branches. Your current branch is implied but you can specify other branches if you wish.

```
 git branch --no-merged integration
```

will show you branches that are not yet merged into `integration` branch.

Answer (score 1):

The below script will find all `origin/*` branches that are ahead of current branch

```
#!/bin/bash

CURRENT_BRANCH=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)

echo -e "Current branch: \e[94m$CURRENT_BRANCH\e[0m"
echo ''

git branch -a | grep remotes/origin/ | while read LINE
do
    CMD="git diff --shortstat remotes/origin/${CURRENT_BRANCH}...${LINE}"

    if $CMD | grep ' file' > /dev/null; then
        echo -e "\e[93m$LINE\e[0m" | sed 's/remotes\/origin\///'
        $CMD
        echo ''
    fi
done
```

Comment: Link is dead.....