# Locally find all unmerged branches of origin

Tags: git, branch

There are lots of resources to find all unmerged branches (e.g. [git finding unmerged branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276001/git-finding-unmerged-branches)), however, I've still not found a solution to show me all unmerged branches ON THE ORIGIN. I've used fetch-all to have all of those branches (ehrr..."refs") on the local site as well.

Still

```
git branch --no-merged develop
```

only outputs:

```
feature/my_feat_1
```

and not

```
origin/feature/my_feat_1
origin/feature/my_feat_2
```

Does anybody know a solution? I cannot access the origin's server directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the `-a` option to the command.  This will list all the branches, both local and remote.

So the command would be:

```
git branch -a --no-merged
```

If you only want to see the remote branches that are not merged in use the `-r` instead.

```
git branch -r --no-merged
```

Be sure that you have done a `git fetch` so that your repo is up-to-date as to the status of all the remote branches.