# Interpreting the output of the "git cherry" command?

Tags: git

I have a Git repository with many branches in it:

```
MYPROJ-1
MYPROJ-12
MYPROJ-73
MYPROJ-115
MYPROJ-217
integration
master
```

I need some way to determine whether a branch has been merged with "master".   A colleague recommended this command:

```
git cherry <thisbranch>  <thatbranch>
```

for example:

```
git cherry MYPROJ-217 master
```

But that appears to only show me what's in the "master" branch that's not in the MYPROJ-217 branch - exactly the opposite of what I want.    If I reverse the arguments, it shows nothing.

Can anybody help me out with this?  I just want to see if a branch has been merged to master or not.

Comment: I have no idea what `git cherry` does, but given what you just described i'd say that output probably means it's merged. If `git cherry MYPROJ-217 master` shows you the commits that are in `master` that aren't in `MYPROJ-217`, then I would expect `git cherry master MYPROJ-217` to show you the commits that are in `MYPROJ-217` that aren't in `master`. If that list is blank, then that would mean there are no commits in `MYPROJ-217` that aren't in `master`, so that branch must be merged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation for `git cherry`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry.html), `git cherry thisbranch thatbranch` would list all the commits that are in `thatbranch` but not in `thisbranch`. So if you run `git cherry master MYPROJ-217` and get no output, then there are no commits in `MYPROJ-217` which aren't in `master`. Therefore, `MYPROJ-217` must have already been merged to master. (Or, perhaps, had it's commits rebased or cherry-picked onto master.)

If all you want is to see what branches aren't merged to master, then this should do what you want:

```
git branch --no-merged master
```

(See: [git finding unmerged branches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12276001/1157054))