# Git - Find all descendant branches not merged in

Tags: git

We have a feature branch "feature" that has many descendant branches that are not merged in.  I would like to find all of these branches so that we can make decisions to merge them in or not.  We have a fairly large git repository and using git branch feature --no-merge shows us hundreds of branches that are not descendants of "feature".

I know that git does not track parent branches so this seems to be a difficult task and I was wondering if anyone has an easy way to find these.

Comment: possible duplicate of [git finding unmerged branches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276001/git-finding-unmerged-branches)

Comment: I am looking to find unmerged branches that are descendants of a specific branch.  The above question does not cover my situation.

Comment: It does if you use `--contains`. Sorry for not mentioning that in the above comment, but in any case torek mentioned it below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the complete list of branches with `git branch --no-merged` and filter against `git branch --contains`.

(I don't know if this works, but it's possible that `git branch --no-merged X --contains X` will do the trick without even requiring running `comm` or equivalent.)

Comment: It does seem to "do the trick"; thanks for this.  I like `git branch -a --no-merged A --contains B` to find all the new "branchlets" introduced since `B` that I might want to bring into `A`.