# Github- How can I find unpublished branches on my local machine?

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I have lots of test branches on my local machine and some old branches which were later merged and deleted from remote repository. How can I find the list of  all such branches?

Note: I don't want to delete all of them without reviewing them once, so a fresh start is not an option for me.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this question: [Viewing Unpushed Git Commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016901/viewing-unpushed-git-commits)

You should be able to use `git log` to get your answer. Specifically...

```
git log --branches --not --remotes
```

To look for unmerged branches: [git finding unmerged branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276001/git-finding-unmerged-branches)

```
git branch --no-merged master
```

Comment: This does not actually give me the list of unpublished branches.I think it just list out commits which are not pushed.

Comment: I found another thing for you to try. Be sure to look at the link for the full description.